# Confusion about rDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email, reverse-dns

I am slightly confused as to what has to go in the rDNS settings of my IP.

Consider the following scenario:

```
IP: 1.2.3.4

Domain 1: foo1.bar
@    A     1.2.3.4
@    MX    mail.foo1.bar    
www  CNAME @
mail CNAME @

Domain 2: foo2.bar
@    A     1.2.3.4
@    MX    mail.foo1.bar

Domain 3: foo3.bar
@    A     1.2.3.4
@    MX    mail.foo1.bar
```

Mails have the format user@foo1.bar, otheruser@foo2.bar, etc. Postfix is set to identify itself as mail.foo1.bar.

What would be the correct rDNS entry for my IP? foo1.bar? mail.foo1.bar?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration should result in all checks being valid in all directions. The SMTP identification should resolve to a valid IP, and the rDNS of that IP should result in a hostname which again forward resolves into a valid IP. Failing any of these checks may result in spamfilter penalties.

Thus in your case mail.foo1.bar would be correct, assuming it also correctly resolves to an IP which reverses to a canonical host.

Comment: What I don't get is if the domain used for sending mail has to match the rDNS 100% or if it's enough if both point to the same IP. That is, if I can use foo1.bar as rDNS and send / receive mail via mail.foo1.bar. Both foo1.bar and mail.foo1.bar resolve to the same IP.

Comment: That should be fine, but it might lead to problems in the future when you get more outward facing servers. It is generally recommended to give every internet-connected host a unique hostname which it uses everywhere, and which *doesn't* match its function - for example `server1.foo.com` which is in its SMTP identifications and resolves correctly on both forward and reverse DNS. That way you're automatically ahead of everything, and you save the headaches when more servers arrive or functions are reassigned between servers.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:
Every machine has to have a name (a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), if possible). In your case it could be `<something>.foo1.bar`, as you use `foo1.bar` as the primary domain. *This* name should be used as reverse DNS and *this* name should be used by services for "identification". Everything else are just service aliases (www, mail, etc).

Comment: OK, given I have "blah.foo1.bar" as FQDN and the machine hostname is "blah", would it be a problem to have "blah.foo1.bar" as rDNS but still use "mail.foo1.bar" in Postfix and as MX?

Comment: Yes, that will be a problem. If the machine's name is `blah.foo1.bar`, then the CNAMEs should point to `blah.foo1.bar`, not `foo1.bar`.